# convert RDB to RDFand mapping two graphs to extract domain terms

Tags: graph, rdf, sparql

I have a table,that stores resources and their tags from social network (bibsonomy)

and i have SPARQL results  from dbpedia by [Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)

[RDF result page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Web_design)

Now, i want to convert that table to RDF graph where every node represents set of tags of a shared resource, then i want to use this rdf result about web_design categories from dbpedia as seed to extract related tags to web design domain .
 i don't know what is the best way and tools to do that .

Comment: As it is, it's not very clear what you're after and/or your question is too broad. Try and narrow it down a bit. In particular, please add specific examples of a) the input data/table; b) the intermediate and final output you want achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much,
Firstly, i want to represent a field in table (mysql) by a graph.
are there any simple tool to do that ?

Comment: @MedEC Even then, it's not quite clear what you want to do.  By "a field" do you mean "a column"?  What's usually more common is that you define a property corresponding to each column, and a new resource for each row, and then you relate the row resource to the column values by the column properties.  E.g., you end up with triples like **:row1 :hasColumn1 "John" . :row1 :hasColumn2 "Smith" . :row1 :hasColumn3 "34"^^xsd:int .**

Comment: thanks, i mean that i have a table with columns like this: 
**row1:has User_id: "1", row1: has Resource_id:"1", row1: has Tag: "network"**<br/>
**row2:has User_id: "1", row2: has Resource_id:"1", row2: has Tag: "wireless".**
**row3:has User_id: "1", row3: has Resource_id:"2", row3: has Tag: "data mining"**
and i wanna transfer that data to a graph, where every row is represented by a node (resource_id column=node identify, tag=properties). If two nodes have at least one tag in common, they will be connected bye an edge.
i read that Jeo4j is a good tool to do that. but i didn't try it.